# Multiple DataContext in data binding, necessary?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-binding, mvvm

In an MVVM design, is it necessary, or even a bad idea, to have multiple DataContext in data binding?

How I thought about MVVM is that the ViewModel should be the one having all the data needed for the View. Thus, the only source object for the DataContext specified in the View is only the ViewModel. The ViewModel will have all the source data the View would want to bind to.

However, I am not sure whether my thoughts are correct and if there are certain situations that really require multiple DataContext that the View would want to bind to.

So, is it a bad idea or practice to have multiple DataContext for the View in data binding? Will just the ViewModel being the only DataContext be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ViewModel should be the only top-level DataContext and it should be set at the root of the View.  However, there may be other sub-DataContexts.  For instance, a ListBox may be bound to a list of data, where the DataContext for each row of the ListBox is bound to one item in the list of data.